# Changing the value of a service when changing routes

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service to change the brand text on a top toolbar based on the active module. Here are the services:

```
export interface IBrand {
  brand: string,
  icon: string,
  url: string,
}


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class BrandService {
  private propertySubject = new BehaviorSubject<IBrand | null>(null);
  property$ = this.propertySubject.asObservable();

  setProperty(obj: IBrand) {
    this.propertySubject.next(obj);
  }
}
```

This BrandService is used in app.component.ts which first initializes the value of the brand service property.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private brandService: BrandService
  ) {
    this.colorSchemeService.load();
    this.brandService.setProperty({
      brand: 'MyCompany',
      icon: 'home',
      url: '/',
    });
  }
}
```

The problem arises when moving pages,
Where the Angular router does this task, for example the HRD module is loaded lazily.

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from "./features/page-not-found/page-not-found.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'hrd',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./features/hrd/hrd.module').then((m) => m.HrdModule),
  },
  {path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'portal',},
  {path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

What happens is when the page moves to the component in the `HRD Module`,
I initialize the text brand when the module is created via `constructor`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [DashboardComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HrdRoutingModule,
  ],
})
export class HrdModule {
  private _brandProperty: IBrand = {
    brand: 'HRD',
    icon: 'supervisor_account',
    url: '/hrd',
  };

  constructor(
    private brandService: BrandService
  ) {
    this.brandService.setProperty(this._brandProperty);
  }
}
```

The following are the brand.components used to create the brand text

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
  template: `
      <app-brand [property]="brandService.property$ | async"></app-brand>
`
})
export class HeaderComponent {
 
  constructor(public brandService: BrandService) {}

}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-brand',
  template: `
<div class="brand-container-fab">
  <button mat-icon-button routerLink="/">
    <mat-icon fontIcon="home"/>
  </button>

  <button mat-button routerLink="{{property?.url}}">
    <mat-icon fontIcon="{{property?.icon}}"/>
    <span>{{property?.brand}}</span>
  </button>
</div>    
`,
  styleUrls: ['./brand.component.scss']
})
export class BrandComponent {

  @Input() property: IBrand | null = null;

}
```

This works normally assuming:

1. The page is loaded the first time, the value is `MyCompany`
2. Move to route HRD, the value is `HRD`
3. Return to the home page, namely app.component.html, the value is wrong, because it is still `hrd`
4. The value should return to its initial value, namely `MyCompany`

Comment: I think the issue is with the angular services and your component lifecycles.  In your BrandService you should store the initial brand value when its first set and in your HrdModule set the brand to "HRD" only if its the initial brand.  At the end in your Appcomponent reset the brand to its inital value when the app is initialized.

Answer (score -1):

When routing back to the home page, the value does not change to the initial value because it is only set in the constructor of the AppComponent.

In order to achieve your desired behavior, I would advice to move the code for setting the property value of the brand service inside the ngOnInit method of the respective component of each module. For example, when the HrdModule is loaded, some HrdPageComponent will hold the logic for setting the property inside the ngOnInit. The same can be done for the component that is active when routing back to home.